# Macro for Excel to refrech Labels Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I work on Excel and I'm not really familiar with macros assigned to charts. Basically I have several charts. I need each of these charts to have labels that corresponds to data in another spreadsheets called "Data_SC". So for instance I would have:

**Graph1:** Label_1 = Data_SC!A1 ; 
Label_2 = Data_SC!A2...

**Graph2:**
Label_1 = Data_SC!B1 ;
Label_2 = Data_SC!B2...

I tried to do it only for the first labels of each charts but I get the error "Type:mismatch". Here is my code:
Sub Refresh_Labels()

```
Dim cht As ChartObjects

For Each cht In Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).HasDataLabels = True
    cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel(1).Text =   Sheets("Data_SC").Range(A1)
Next cht

End Sub
```

Could you guys help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub Refresh_Labels()
Dim cht As ChartObject

For Each cht In Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).HasDataLabel = True
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Text = Sheets("Data_SC").Range("A1")
Next cht

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help DiegoAndresJAY but unfortunately that still doesn't work

Comment: Ok, updated...not sure where I got what I posted. Try again.